# Create Ecto query with dynamic operators

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I know how I can use dynamic fields and values into Ecto query, for example:

```
field = :age
value = 20
Ecto.Query.where(App.User, [x], field(x, ^field) < ^value)
```

But, it is possible to define the operator (in this example `<`) dynamically? and how?

I have tried it with `fragment` and interpolated string:

```
operator = ">"
Ecto.Query.where(App.User, [x], fragment("? #{operator} ?", field(x, ^field), ^value))
```

but it raises the exception: `Ecto.Query.CompileError) to prevent SQL injection attacks, fragment(...) does not allow strings...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, with a bit of metaprogramming. [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) supports custom macros.

```rb
defmacrop custom_where(t, f, v, sign) do
  {sign, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel],
   [
     {:field, [], [t, {:^, [], [f]}]},
     {:^, [], [v]}
   ]}
end
```

And use it like

```rb
field = :age
value = 20

Ecto.Query.where(User, [x],
  custom_where(x, field, value, :<))
#⇒ #Ecto.Query<from u0 in User, where: u0.age < ^20>
```

The trick here is that we fool [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) injecting an AST inplace, so it does not perform checks.

Comment: It does not work when pass sign from variable: `Ecto.Query.where(User, [x], custom_where(x, field, value, sign)`. It shows this error: `(Ecto.Query.CompileError) sign(field(x, ^field), ^value) is not a valid query expression` Any suggest ?

Comment: It obviously does not work that way because what gets passed to _macros_ is an AST. It should be handled differently, probably with an explicit quoting the outcome of the macro and unquoting the variable passed inside the quote block.